# Filemaker: values form related table

Tags: filemaker

I have 2 tables, `DATA` and `IMAGES`, in a relationship based on `item_number`.
Records in `DATA` each have 3 records from `IMAGES` gathered.

For example, a record with `item_number` 010050 is linked to these records in `IMAGES`:

- 010050.eps
- 010050_table.tif
- 010050_drawing.png

In the corresponding record in DATA I have the fields:

- `main`
- `table`
- `drawing`

My aim is to set the fields in DATA like:

- 010050.eps => main
- 010050_table.tif => table
- 010050_drawing.png => drawing

I tried:

```
ExecuteSQL("SELECT filename FROM images WHERE filename = ?"; ""; ""; "010050_drawing")
```

Who could give me a hint?

Comment: Why would you need these extra fields? You could simply display the related records in a *portal* - if necessary, with a calculated label (presumably based on the file's extension?).

Comment: Your SQL query does not work as your parameter missing ".png" at the end, so it would not match, but as everyone mentioned here, I am not sure that your approach is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't figure out how I can do that in xslt.

To take a simplified example, suppose you have exported from your `Data` table, with only two fields included in the export: `Data::ItemNumber` and `Images::FileName`. Your raw export would then look something like this (two records shown):

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
   <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
   <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION=""/>
   <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
   <METADATA>
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ItemNumber" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Images::FileName" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
   </METADATA>
   <RESULTSET FOUND="2">
      <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="1">
         <COL>
            <DATA>010050</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>010050.eps</DATA>
            <DATA>010050_table.tif</DATA>
            <DATA>010050_drawing.png</DATA>
         </COL>
       </ROW>
      <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="2">
         <COL>
            <DATA>2345</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>2345_extra.gif</DATA>
            <DATA>2345_table.gif</DATA>
            <DATA>2345_drawing.jpg</DATA>
            <DATA>2345.tiff</DATA>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
   </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

*Note the different order as well as the extra image in the second record.*

After applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
            <xsl:variable name="item-no" select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
            <item>
                <number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$item-no"/>
                </number>
                <main>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA[starts-with(., concat($item-no, '.'))]"/>
                </main>
                <table>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA[starts-with(., concat($item-no, '_table.'))]"/>
                </table>
                <drawing>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA[starts-with(., concat($item-no, '_drawing.'))]"/>
                </drawing>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you would obtain:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item>
      <number>010050</number>
      <main>010050.eps</main>
      <table>010050_table.tif</table>
      <drawing>010050_drawing.png</drawing>
   </item>
   <item>
      <number>2345</number>
      <main>2345.tiff</main>
      <table>2345_table.gif</table>
      <drawing>2345_drawing.jpg</drawing>
   </item>
</root>
```

Comment: that's extremely helpful! This is a huge step forward. Much simpler. I just discovered that the item_number have not always 6 positions as I initially thought. If I will use this approach it frees me from tackling this problem as well. thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, unless there's more happening than what you've described, you're making this too hard.

If there will always be exactly 3 IMAGE records for each DATA record, and especially if you want to directly relate each image to a specific type, you don't need the IMAGE table. A much simpler solution would be to add 3 container fields to your DATA table (say, main_image, table_image, drawing_image). You wouldn't need SQL or a portal, and you wouldn't have to worry about keeping related images linked to their type.

OTOH, if you truly need a separate table, consider hard-wiring three dedicated 1:1 relationships, one for each image type. To do this, add 3 special key fields in DATA: (main_image_id, etc.) and create a relationship for each image type, each between one of these fields and the primary IMAGE. Then, whenever you create a DATA record and 3 related IMAGE records, put the key of the matching image in the matching DATA::xxx_image_id field. That way, you'd have a clean 1:1 relationship, and each related image would be locked to its type.

Comment: Brian, OP already has a working relationship and can get data through it. Why does he need another three 1:1?

Comment: Nicolai, it sounds like there are exactly 3 images for each DATA record, and each needs to be locked to a matching type. A standard relationship can order the related records, but that's a weak way of locking each of the 3 related image records; what if the first or second gets deleted, etc.? The 1:1 relationships are *one* way of storing IMAGE data in a separate table, while keeping each related image locked cleanly to its type no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies

I need the value of the images in those fields to get it exported to XML and InDesign (into table cells).
The issue is that I know the filenames , namely the item_number followed by  _drawing or _table, but don't know the extension on forehand (many files and from different sources)
File formats  differ therefore.
My solution now is:
- imported all the images in a related (item_number, his is also part of the filename) a FMP table
- I calculated whether the file is a table, drawing or illustration and put those values in a field 'kind' by:

```
Case (
  PatternCount ( filename ; "_drawing." )  ;
  "drawing" ;

  PatternCount ( filename ; "_table." ) ;
  "table" ;

  Length ( filename )=10 ;
  "main" ;

  ""
)
```

- then I did the query in each of the fields, main - table - drawing. The one below is the calculation in the 'table' field.

```
ExecuteSQL("
  SELECT path_xml 
  FROM images 
  WHERE item_number = ? and kind = ?";
  "";""; item_number ; "table"); ""
)
```

Perhaps a bit clumsy, but it works now.

Comment: "*I need the value of the images in those fields to get it exported to XML*" FYI, when you export, you can include related fields in the export field order. There is no need to add **anything** to the file's schema if its only purpose is to serve another application. All the logic can be handled by the XSLT stylesheet (which you presumably have).

Comment: thanks, I thought about that. Each image file needs to go in the dedicated cell in the I D table. EG: the 123456_drawing.eps goes in the cell in the cell meant to contain the drawings. I couldn't figure out how I can do that in xslt. I would have made life easier probably and getting a cleaner and leaner FMP table is also an advantage.